# Creating a pop up that moves to the side after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, animation, popup

I’m a novice in web design but I can usually achieve what I want using css, html and plugins in WordPress. 
I want to create a popup that appears when the homepage loads and then hides off to the side after a few seconds. For a visualization, this site does it exactly. 
https://pupunzi.com

Is this possible with just css and html or would I have to learn to use java scripts?